# What pitch is proper for a cement apron in front of a garage? I'm referring to water drainage

Tags: concrete

I'm having a cement slab,(apron), poured in front of my garage. What is the proper pitch for water drainage necessary?

Comment: I was always taught 1/4 bubble for drainage or 1/4” per foot. If just an apron I would maintain this, however a slab some think this is two extreme. I have seen areas on the coast that 1/4 bubble on the sea side of the house was not enough and a step or lip was needed but on the other side of the house 1/8 bubble was more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

*Minimum slope* (*i.e* what "flat" things outdoors are sloped to by competent workers - totally flat is generally not a good practice due to not draining) is 1% - 1 cm per meter, or (close enough at 1.04%) 1/8" per foot.

If more is convenient, it won't hurt for drainage, and generally won't bother an automobile entering - 6% is not uncommon on roads. Some driveways are much steeper than that, but they can become problematic in winter, if you have winter.

Answer (score 0):

A pitch which causes the water to flow away from the garage is a good pitch. In terms of water: The steeper, the better.

You might laugh at this saying it is not an answer to your question, but blowing heavy rain or a driveway that leans toward the garage can move a lot of water the wrong way and your car will not drive up a wall.

Proper seal against water at a garage door is a one inch step on the other side of the garage door because a garage door always allows some water that blows against the door to enter. This is accomplished by attaching a 2x4 to the form where the garage door closes before pouring the garage floor. If you cannot do this, then a small step outside right before the door would be a good idea. You can also grind existing concrete where the door closes to make it slope outward.

Answer (score 0):

Is the apron covered? Do you have stormy weather or periods of heavy rainfall?

How about large snow packs?

All this matters.

Keep heavy rain flowing away from garage, and make sure melting snow does not puddle and refreeze to cause slip hazard. For this you need at least 1"/4' pitch. This is an accepted general pre-caution for insurance & liability.

You can pitch forward or sideways from center.

Also prepare for turbulent weather as climate changes: mild now can be wild later.